# Format x-axis tick labels to seams like the default pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to set my plot xticks to similar to the pandas dataframe default format.

I've been trying to set using the plt.set_xticklabels functions, but did not succeed.

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(len(stations), 2, figsize=(10,11))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05)
hPc3.plot(use_index=True, subplots=True, ax=axarr[0:len(stations),0], 
for i in range(0,len(axarr)):
    axarr[i,0].set_ylabel('$nT$')
axarr[len(stations)-1,0].set_xlabel('$(UT)$')
for i in range(0,len(axarr)):
    plot4 = axarr[i,1].pcolormesh(tti, wPc3_period[i], np.log10(abs(wPc3_power[i])), cmap = 'jet')
    axarr[i,1].set_yscale('log', basey=2, subsy=None)
    axarr[i,1].set_xlabel('$(UT)$')
    axarr[i,1].set_ylabel('$Period$ $(s)$')
    axarr[i,1].set_ylim([np.min(wPc3_period[i]), np.max(wPc3_period[i])])
    axarr[i,1].invert_yaxis()
    axarr[i,1].plot(tti, te_coi3, 'w')
    cbar_coord = replace_at_index1(make_axes_locatable(axarr[i,1]).get_position(), [0,2], [0.92, 0.01])
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes(cbar_coord)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(plot4, cax=cbar_ax,  boundaries=np.linspace(-10, 10, 512),
                    ticks=[-10, -5, 0, 5, 10], label='$log_{2}$')
    cbar.set_clim([-10,5])
```

the left panel show the default label of pandas data frame plot. The right panel is how is my formatation

[image: the left panel show the default label of pandas data frame plot. The right panel is how is my formatation]

Comment: Does the image have graphs for same data? Can you produce a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib [dates](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) api provides plenty of convenience functions and classes to represent and convert date and time data.

You can reproduce `pandas` style using a simple combination of `DateFormatter`, `DayLocator` and `HourLocator`. Here's an example on a dummy dataset given you didn't provide complete working code, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt to your use case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# create toy dataset
index = pd.date_range("2018-05-25 00:00:00", "2018-05-26 00:00:00", freq = "1min")
series = pd.Series(np.random.random(len(index)), index=index)
x = index.to_pydatetime()
y = series

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,1))
ax = fig.gca()

ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=3))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', labelrotation=30)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d-%b"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.tick_params(which='major', pad=10, labelrotation=30)

ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())

ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]